# Triangle inequality involving side lengths and circumradius

Tags: triangles, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> For a $\triangle ABC$ with side lengths $a,b,c$ and circumradius $R$ prove that-

> $a+b+c\leq 3\sqrt3 R$

Now we know that $R=\frac{abc}{4\Delta}$ where $\Delta$ denotes area of triangle. So I tried to reduce inequality as follows to find hint of using $AM-GM$

$a+b+c\leq 3\sqrt3 \frac{abc}{4\Delta}$

$(a+b+c)^2\leq 27 \frac{(abc)^2}{16\Delta^2}$

$\displaystyle(a+b+c)^3(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)\leq  \frac{27(abc)^2}{16}$

Now I know that which terms I have to incorporate  in $AM-GM$ but I'm not able to correctly use them

Please provide me hint so that I can proceed forward

Comment: Several hi(n)ts from [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a%2Bb%2Bc%5Cleq%203%5Csqrt3%20R%24&p=1), as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the sine rule
$$ a = 2R\sin A$$
$$ b = 2R\sin B$$
$$ c = 2R\sin C$$
Now, you have to prove that
$$2R\sin A + 2R\sin B + 2R\sin C \le 3\sqrt3R$$
$$  \sin A + \sin B+ \sin C \le \dfrac{3\sqrt3}{2}$$
Can you complete it from here?

Hint:
This can be easily proved using Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Yes now I can take it forward since$\ sin x$ is convex up for the interval $(0,\pi)$, Therefore $(\sin A+\sin B+\sin c)/3 \leq \sin( (A+B+C)/3)=\sqrt{3}/2$

Answer (score 1):

We know that $R \ge 2r$$R \ge 2r=\frac{2Δ}{s}=2\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s}}\ge 2(\frac{3s-a-b-c}{3})^\frac32\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}=2(\frac{s}{3})^\frac32\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}=\frac{2s}{3\sqrt3}=\frac{a+b+c}{3\sqrt3}$

Comment: I didn't about this inequality but now it's clear thanks for your help

Comment: @LalitTolani Here's proof why $R\ge 2r$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/171641/742113)