# Let a, b, and c be the sides of a triangle. Prove that $(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)\leq abc$

Tags: geometry, inequality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove $(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) \leq abc$, where $a, b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170813/prove-abca-bcab-c-leq-abc-where-a-b-and-c-are-positive-real)

The title says it all. I've been trying to prove this for hours! Help me!

Comment: try expanding the expression and apply triangle inequality

Comment: when I said that "I've been trying to prove this for hours", what I meant was I've been trying to incorporate triangle inequality in order to prove this.

The thing is that both abc and (a+b−c)(b+c−a)(c+a−b) are greater or equal than 0. And I can't seem to connect them together in one equation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was wrong.

Use  the substitution $a=x+y$, $b=y+z$ and $c=z+x$ in the initial inequality to have $$8xyz\le(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$$ and that follows directly from $AM-GM$ since

$$\begin{array}{ll}x+y\ge 2\sqrt{xy}\\ y+z\ge 2\sqrt{yz}\\ z+x\ge 2\sqrt{zx}\\(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)\ge 8\sqrt{x^2y^2z^2}=8xyz\\  \end{array}$$

**NB:** $AM-GM$ applies only because the sides of a triangle are positive, thus $a,b,c>0$.

Comment: something is wrong, the inequality says $\le$ and i have negative values in my expression.

Comment: I think you screwed up the multiplication.

Comment: nope, your multiplication is good.