# $x$, $y$ and $z$ are sides of a triangle - prove that $(x+y-z)(x-y+z)(-x+y+z)\leq xyz$

Tags: geometry

$x$, $y$ and $z$ are all sides of a triangle. Prove that
$(x+y-z)(x-y+z)(-x+y+z)\leq xyz$.

Equality occurs when all sides are the same length. 
I don't know how to prove that the left side is *always* less or equal though.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange. Please, show us your effort.

Comment: See [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1023485/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236725/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

writing your inequality with the variables $a,b,c$

$(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)\le abc$
using the Ravi-Substitution

$a=y+z,b=x+z,c=x+y$ so your inequality is equivalent to

$(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)\geq 8xyz$

this AM-GM.